# Uploading audio files without paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, file-upload, amazon-s3

I want to have my users be able to upload audio files.

I've done some research on this and found Paperclip. However, I've also read that Paperclip performs poorly if the file is over 4MB, and as you probably know most audio files are over 4MB.

So my question is, how can I have users upload audio files without using Paperclip? I plan on storing everything in Amazon S3.

I plan on users being able to stream this audio and download the files, if that makes any difference.

Comment: i dont think stackoverflos is the right site to ask this kind of questions ...